# How can one shows that, $(-1)^s+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)^s}=\sum_{k=0}^{s-2}(-1)^k\zeta(s-k)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Valid for all Integers $s\ge2$

How can one shows that,

$$(-1)^s+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)^s}=\sum_{k=0}^{s-2}(-1)^k\zeta(s-k)$$

Where $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^s}$

Comment: This is a lot to work with, so it might help if you posted some of your work on the problem.

Comment: I don't even know where to start on tackling this problem, but it is my maths problem not from some text book question.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know where to start either. The only thing I can think of is subtracting $(-1)^s$, so you get $-(-1)^s=+(-1)^{s-1}$ on the right side, which kind of extends the summation on the right side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's simply inverse the two sums (formal derivation) :
\begin{align}
f(s)&:=\sum_{k=0}^{s-2}(-1)^k\zeta(s-k)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{s-2}(-1)^k\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^{s-k}}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^{s}}\sum_{k=0}^{s-2}\frac{(-1)^k}{(n+1)^{-k}}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^{s}}\sum_{k=0}^{s-2}(-(n+1))^k\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^{s}}\frac{1-(-(n+1))^{s-1}}{1+n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)^{s}}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{s}}{(n+1)(n+2)}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)^s}+(-1)^s\\
\end{align}
(using telescoping to conclude since $\dfrac 1{(n+1)(n+2)}=\dfrac 1{n+1}-\dfrac 1{n+2}$)

Comment: This is a really cool derivation! I know I'm not the original questioner, but thanks!

Comment: Glad you liked it @Noble Mushtak! Excellent continuation,

Comment: Nicely done! +1

Comment: Excellent @Raymond Manzoni and (+1)

Comment: Why is on hold? How is this off topic if someone can solve it and deliver a beautiful answer. I don't get it.

Comment: I am looking at this answer again I really love it. All that time I haven't got a clue. Amazing @Raymon MAnzoni

Comment: Glad it pleased you @pisquare. A neat little problem indeed,

Comment: Do you know why is this problem is On a hold. Did I wrote something wrong?

Comment: @pisquare: I don't see mistakes in the formulation. The question was possibly a little short (your thoughts and attempts should make it better). Excellent continuation anyway,

Comment: @pisquare Why on hold? Maybe because "This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level", who knows?

Comment: I have difficulties with your 4, the answer is brilliant can't you 4 brain see it